# Azure AD B2C Custom identity provider

Tags: azure, active-directory, multi-tenant

I am testing azure B2C AD, I followed this tutorial:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet/

I have tested login with "local account" and Facebook everything is working perfect. I see that I can add a custom identity provider.

Can I add another Azure AD (not B2C) so that the users from that AD can login into my web application ?

Comment: Not sure if your wanting to still do this but now with custom policies in private preview, you could create a custom policy that would redirect your user to another Azure AD instance log in and redirect back to your B2C

Answer (score 1):

Adding another Tenant or allowing any other AAD Tenant are currently on the backlog. It is not possible to do those at this time.

Please do share your scenario so that we evaluate it in the planning.

thank you,
Vikram.

Comment: Vikram, a simple example would be to achieve a single web API layer that can be used with authenticated users from Azure AD B2C, Azure AD B2B, or non-Azure ADFS instance or any protocol compatible identity provider.  As it is right now, it seems like it's not very straightforward to do with Azure AD B2C using `UseOAuthBearerAuthentication` and B2B using `UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication` at the web application level.

Comment: I would like to know when this functionality is released?